# Loop through array of objects to display each value in a grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, javascript-objects

Currently I only get the first value of each object inside itemList:

| name | description | details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |

```
itemList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "item1",
    description: "description1",
    details: "detail1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "item2",
    description: "description1",
    details: "detail2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "item3",
    description: "description1",
    details: "detail3"
  }
];

function Items() {
  const handleRender = () => {
    return itemList.map((item) => {
      for (let entry in item) {
        return (
          <div className="grid-item" key={item.id}>
            {item[entry]}
          </div>
        );
      }
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="grid-container">
      <div className="grid-item">name</div>
      <div className="grid-item">description</div>
      <div className="grid-item">details</div>

      {handleRender()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried to loop in different ways, but I either get one div with all the itemList entries as one grid-item, or only the first value of each object.

I want to have three columns:

| name | description | details |
| --- | --- | --- |
| item1 | description1 | details1 |
| item2 | description2 | details1 |
| item3 | description3 | details1 |

How can I achieve this?

Is it even possible using CSS grid?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML table to produce this type of output
For example

```
 <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>description</th>
            <th>details</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {
            itemList.map((item) => {
              return <tr>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.description}</td>
                <td>{item.details}</td>
              </tr>
            })
          }

        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can refactor *handleRender*
something like this

```
 const handleRender = () => {
    return itemList.map((item) => {
      return Object.keys(item).map((key, index) => {
        return (
          <div className="grid-item" key={item.id}>
            {item[key]}
          </div>
        );
      });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single `map` function to display your items. And use the properties to display the 'cells'.

```js
export default function Items() {
  return (
    <div className="grid-container">
      <div className="grid-item">name</div>
      <div className="grid-item">description</div>
      <div className="grid-item">details</div>
      {itemList.map((item) => {
        return (
          <>
            <div className="grid-item">{item.name}</div>
            <div className="grid-item">{item.description}</div>
            <div className="grid-item">{item.details}</div>
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Your css could look something like this.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a loop, you can use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get an array of the properties for a JavaScript object, then outputting the `td` elements for a table is as straightforward as the technique that you already successfully used to `.map` its rows.

You can also follow the same technique to extract the column names for the header.  Just get them from the first row.  Note, this doesn't work for an empty table: with no rows, you won't get a header.  It's also sensitive to property order, so be careful to normalize your data.

You have omitted the `id` property from your example table, so I've used `.filter` to remove it here as well.

```js
const itemList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "item1",
    description: "description1",
    details: "detail1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "item2",
    description: "description1",
    details: "detail2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "item3",
    description: "description1",
    details: "detail3"
  }
];

function Table(props) {
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {
            Object.entries(props.rows[0])
              .filter(([key, value]) => key !== 'id')
              .map(([key, value]) => (<th key={key}>{ key }</th>))
          }
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {
          props.rows.map(row => (
            <tr>
              {
                Object.entries(row)
                  .filter(([key, value]) => key !== 'id')
                  .map(([key, value]) => (<td key={key}>{ value }</td>))
              }
            </tr>
          ))
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table rows={ itemList } />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table, th, td { border: 1px solid; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I intentionally did not use grid-template-columns because your problem seemed to be centered around how to get the properties in an array, not how to use grid CSS.  But if you prefer to see it all spelled out in grid CSS form let me know.